# java1.6, MyEclipse 7.1.1

Tags: java, myeclipse

Project title: "A Cross-Layer Approach-Based Gnutella for Collaborative Virtual Environments over Mobile Ad Hoc Networks".

I got following error while executing the project:

```
java.net.SocketException: IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP failed (out of hardware filters?)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(Unknown Source)
    at com.multicast.MulticastRx.run(MulticastRx.java:103)
java.net.SocketException: IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP failed (out of hardware filters?)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.join(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(Unknown Source)
    at com.multicast.MulticastTx.run(MulticastTx.java:31)
```

Comment: Are you saying there's code to go with [this](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/TPDS.2009.91)?

Comment: Have you talked to the project authors?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Error on MulticastSocket.joinGroup()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534551/error-on-multicastsocket-joingroup). They seem to be getting the same error as yours.