# ActiveMQ installation error

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am completely new to ActiveMQ and am trying to install the same on my system using Windows 7.

I downloaded the `activemq-4.0` binary version and tried following the instructions on Apache portal. After installing when I run the `activemq.bat` in `bin` folder or run the same command from cmd, I get the following exception :

```
java.net.SocketException:IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP failed(out of Hardware Filters)
```

I tried searching the same error but I am gaining no context out of the explanations. I have no clue of the error.

Comment: Why in the world are you using such an antiquated version?  The latest is 5.7.0

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably JVM preferred IPv6 stack.  (Before 2.1 we were disabling IPv6 by setting system property 'java.net.preferIPv4Stack'.)
Try explicitly setting `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Refer this link [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534551/error-on-multicastsocket-joingroup).